# How can ı create function to show how many string in a given list with while and for loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
def count_strings( items ):
i = 0 
for item in items:
    if(type(item) == str):
        i += 1


print(items.count(items)
```

ı was trying to do with for loop and while loop but ı can't.
ı should print out 6.
From this list;

items = ['apple', 55, 1.2, 'banana', lambda a: a, 
         'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""", -2,
         '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code
function count_strings always returns None;
no class items and no its method count are defined.

Code below prints correct result.

```
    def count_strings(items):
    i = 0
    for item in items: 
        if(type(item) == str):
            i += 1
    return i

t =  ['apple', 55, 1.2, 'banana', lambda a: a, 'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""", -2, '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]

print(count_strings(t))
```

Comment: thank you so much @Yuri Gİnsburg .
but ı wonder how  to write those codes with while  loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: You can use a `while` loop to iterate through a list, just as easily as using a `for` loop.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/ for examples using both methods.

Comment: Thx for the comment i will check.